# React useEffect cleanup function unexpectedly called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a custom hook to fetch api on form submit, I make the api call inside an useEffect hook and I have a reducer to handle the hook's states.
One of the states is `trigger` set to false at first which controls if the useEffect do anything, the point is the hook returns a function that flips `trigger` value which triggers the useEffect only when you call this function.
The problem is the useEffect's cleanup function is called during the api call even though the component is clearly still mounted.

The cleanup function seems to be fired because I set the value of `trigger` based on its previous value, when I set `trigger` to a fixed value the cleanup function is not called but I lose my functionality

```
const fetchReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_TRIGGER':
            return {
                ...state,
                trigger: !state.trigger
            }
        case 'FETCH_INIT':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
                isError: false
            };
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: false,
                datas: action.payload,
            };
        case 'FETCH_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: true,
            };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

const useFetchApi = (query, initialData = []) => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        datas: initialData,
        trigger: false
    });
    const triggerFetch = _ => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TRIGGER' });
    const cancel = _ => { console.log("canceling");isCancelled = true };

    useEffect(_ => {
        if (!state.trigger)
            return;
        triggerFetch();
        (async _ => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });
            try {
                const datas = await query();
                if (!isCancelled) { //isCancelled is true at this point
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: datas })
                }
            } catch (err) {
                if (!isCancelled) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE', payload: err })
                }
            }
        })();
        return cancel;
    }, [state.trigger]);
    return { ...state, triggerFetch};
}
```

Usage:

```
function MyComponent () {
    const { datas, isLoading, isError, triggerFetch } = useFetchApi(query);
    return (
        <form onSubmit={event => {event.preventDefault(); triggerFetch()}}>
...
```

Comment: The cleanup function is invoked every time the effect is run again as well as on unmount, and in your case it will be run every time `state.trigger` changes.

Comment: The cleanup function returned from an effect is only ever explicitly called on unmount if you pass an empty array as the second argument. Otherwise, the clean up function will be called whenever something in the dependency array changes.

Comment: You could add another use effect that didn't do anything except for return that `cancel` function and have it with an empty array dependency that would mimic `componentWillUnmount` like `useEffect(() => cancel, [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by Tom Finney from the comments:

`You could add another use effect that didn't do anything except for return that cancel function and have it with an empty array dependency that would mimic componentWillUnmount like useEffect(() => cancel, [])`

```
const useFetchApi = (query, initialData = []) => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        datas: initialData,
        trigger: false
    });
    const triggerFetch = _ => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TRIGGER' });
    const cancel = _ => { console.log("canceling");isCancelled = true };

    useEffect(_ => {
        if (!state.trigger)
            return;
        triggerFetch();
        (async _ => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });
            try {
                const datas = await query();
                if (!isCancelled) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: datas })
                }
            } catch (err) {
                if (!isCancelled) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE', payload: err })
                }
            }
        })();
    }, [state.trigger]);
    useEffect(_=> cancel, []) //remove return cancel from useEffect and replace by this

    return { ...state, triggerFetch};
}
```

Comment: And does this actually work? Shouldn't it be `useEffect(()=> () => cancel(), [])`?

Comment: @Gatoyu I don't think this solution will successfully cancel on unmount. The `cancel` function in the second effect will always be the `cancel` from the initial render which will change the `isCancelled` variable from the initial render. Calling `triggerFetch` will trigger a re-render which means the first effect (the one that calls `query`) will be using an `isCancelled` from the re-render which will **not** be changed by the second effect. This is why a ref is needed.

Answer (score 4):

A local variable can be used inside the useEffect callback. Credit to @gaearon

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0lm13kwxo

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;

    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await axios('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=' + query);
      if (!ignore) setData(result.data);
    }

    fetchData();
    return () => { ignore = true; }
  }, [query]);
```

Answer (score 2):

2 things to keep in mind:

1. The clean-up callback runs **every time the useEffect runs**; that **excludes** the component's **mount** and **includes** the component's **unmount**. If you want to simulate a componentWillUnMount, use a useEffect with an empty array of dependencies.
2. The clean-up callback runs **before** the rest of the code inside the useEffect. This is important to remember for a useEffect that has dependencies since it will be called when any of the dependencies changes and both the clean-up callback and the rest of the code inside the effect are run. This is the componentDidUpdate behavior.

If you ask me, the name clean-up is misleading. The callback actually runs before the rest of the code in componentDidUpdate scenarios, so it's not as much clean-up as it is prep in that regard. The title clean-up is only deserved on unmount.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are triggering a state change which will trigger a re-render which will trigger an effect which will then call your API. All you really want to do is call your API.

In the sample code below, I've changed `triggerFetch` to actually execute the query and removed the `trigger` state. I added an effect without dependencies to allow cancelling on unmount. I also changed the cancel approach to use a ref rather than a local variable so that it will persist across re-renders.

```
import { useReducer, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const fetchReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_INIT":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false
      };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        datas: action.payload
      };
    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const useFetchApi = (query, initialData = []) => {
  const cancelledRef = useRef(false);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    datas: initialData,
    trigger: false
  });
  const triggerFetch = async _ => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_INIT" });
    try {
      const datas = await query();
      if (!cancelledRef.current) {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: datas });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (!cancelledRef.current) {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAILURE", payload: err });
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(_ => {
    return _ => {
      console.log("canceling");
      cancelledRef.current = true;
    };
  }, []);
  return { ...state, triggerFetch };
};

export default useFetchApi;
```