# Next.js: Issue with useEffect cleanup closing a modal. Why is the cleanup function being fired?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am implementing a modal dialog using Next.JS version 12.3.1. I want my modal to open immediatelly and display a loading message while a request is performed, then display the request result.

But for some reason, when the request result is resolved, the modal closes.

What have I tried in order to solve the problem:

- I tried creating a separate useEffect just to deal with the cleanup
- I tried creating a useEffect with an empty array of dependencies to detect component mounting
- I tried memoizing everything
- I tried using useLayoutEffect (looks like Next.Js does not care about this)
- I tried some complex logic inside the useEffect cleanup function just to prevent the modal from closing

I also searched extensively in the internet and tried many different examples, but I am sure I am either not getting a fundamental of React or I am missing something I don't even know what it is.

This is my `soon.tsx` page:

```
// lots of import statements here

type SubscriptionResponse = {
  success: boolean;
  message: TeaserSubscriptionResponseMessage;
};

export const SoonPage: NextPage = () => {
  const [subscriptionResponse, setSubscriptioResponse] = useState<SubscriptionResponse>();
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const debounceTimer = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!inputRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  const registerEmail: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (debounceTimer.current) {
      return;
    }

    setIsModalVisible(true);

    const target = event.target as typeof event.target & {
      email: { value: string };
    };
    const email = target.email.value;

    fetch("/api/subscribe-to-newsletter", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setSubscriptioResponse(response);
      });

    debounceTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      debounceTimer.current = undefined;
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const closeModal = () => {
    console.log("SoonPage", "closeModal");
    setSubscriptioResponse(undefined);
    setIsModalVisible(false);
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <TitleAndMetaTags
          prependTitle="we're coming soon!"
          description="Em breve traremos novidades!"
        />
        <main className={styles.mainContent}>
          <article>
            <p>shhhhhhh! </p>
            <p>
              yo! a gente tá quase chegando... com tudo! 
              <br />
              você não perde por esperar o que vem por aí.
            </p>
            <p>
              enquanto espera, deixe seu e-mail mais cool aqui embaixo pra gente mandar um yo quando
              chegar:
            </p>
            <form action="/soon" method="post" onSubmit={registerEmail}>
              <Input
                autoFocus
                className={styles.emailInput}
                id="teaser-email-input"
                name="email"
                placeholder="seu e-mail"
                ref={inputRef}
                required
                tabIndex={0}
                type="email"
              />
              <br />
              <Button
                autoFocus={false}
                id="teaser-subscribe-button"
                shouldDebounce={false}
                tabIndex={1}
              >
                Cadastrar
              </Button>
            </form>
            <p>see ya soon. peace out.</p>
            <figure className={styles.logo}>
              <Image src={YoLogoWithTrademark} width={165} alt="Yo! Inglês" />
            </figure>
          </article>
        </main>
      </div>
      <SubscriptionResponseModal
        isModalVisible={isModalVisible}
        onClose={closeModal}
        subscriptionResponse={subscriptionResponse}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default SoonPage;

type SubscriptionResponseModalProps = {
  isModalVisible: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  subscriptionResponse?: SubscriptionResponse;
};

const SubscriptionResponseModal = memo(function SubscriptionResponseModal({
  isModalVisible,
  onClose,
  subscriptionResponse,
}: SubscriptionResponseModalProps) {
  console.log("SubscriptionResponseModal", { isModalVisible, subscriptionResponse });
  return (
    <Modal className={modalStyles.modal} isOpen={isModalVisible} onClose={onClose}>
      {subscriptionResponse ? 'Loading' : 'Finished'}
      <form method="dialog">
        <Button autoFocus>ok</Button>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
});
```

And this is my `Modal.tsx` component

```
import { memo, ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

type ModalProps = {
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
  className: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
};

function Modal({ children, className, isOpen, onClose }: ModalProps) {
  const [dialogElementRef, setDialogElementRef] = useState<HTMLDialogElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const dialogElementRef = document.getElementById("modal") as HTMLDialogElement;
    setDialogElementRef(dialogElementRef);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dialogElementRef === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    dialogElementRef.addEventListener("close", onClose);
    dialogElementRef.classList.add(className);

    console.log("Modal.tsx", { isOpen });

    if (isOpen) {
      dialogElementRef.showModal();
    } else {
      console.log("Modal.tsx", "closing modal");
      dialogElementRef.close();
    }

    return () => {
      console.log("Modal.tsx", "useEffect cleanup");
      dialogElementRef.close();
      dialogElementRef.removeEventListener("close", onClose);
      dialogElementRef.classList.remove(className);
    };
  }, [className, dialogElementRef, isOpen, onClose]);

  if (dialogElementRef && isOpen) {
    return createPortal(children, dialogElementRef);
  }

  return null;
}

export default memo(Modal);
```

I tried creating a separate useEffect just to deal with the cleanup
I tried creating a useEffect with an empty array of dependencies to detect component mounting
I tried memoizing everything
I tried using useLayoutEffect (looks like Next.Js does not care about this)
I tried some complex logic inside the useEffect cleanup function just to prevent the modal from closing

Those are some questions I tried to look at before posting this one, but the scenarios are different and I was not able to get anything useful out of them:

[React useEffect cleanup function unexpectedly called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376471/react-useeffect-cleanup-function-unexpectedly-called) <- didn't help

[reactjs useEffect cleanup function after fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811352/reactjs-useeffect-cleanup-function-after-fetching-data) <- unrelated

I expect that some member of the community can help me figure out why the modal is closing when the request is resolved

Comment: Your `useEffect` as presented above is not doing anything.  You declared it has no dependencies, so it will run once and only once when the component is rendered and the `inputRef` will not be set at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a dependency in one of the `useEffect` hooks was changing its identity. The faulting dependency was the `closeModal` function from the `soon.tsx` page. In order to solve it I needed to use the `useCallback` hook in order to memoize it:

So, in the `soon.tsx` page, instead of this:

```
  const closeModal = () => {
    console.log("SoonPage", "closeModal");
    setSubscriptioResponse(undefined);
    setIsModalVisible(false);
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  };
```

I need to have this:

```
  const closeModal = useCalback(() => {
    console.log("SoonPage", "closeModal");
    setSubscriptioResponse(undefined);
    setIsModalVisible(false);
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, []);
```